# Sending mouse clicks by contracting abdominal muscles

Tags: mice

I am looking for a device that would allow me to send mouse clicks to a laptop by contracting abdominal muscles.

Ideally, it can detect when abdominal muscles stay contracted, in which case one can configure to either send click at regular interval (i.e. every X miliseconds), or hold left click down to allow for drag and drop, area selection, etc.

Any price, operating system requirements, and geographical availability is fine.

I didn't find the [Makey Makey](http://makeymakey.com/) convenient for that use.

Comment: How much work are you willing to put into it? I vaguely remember a similar project on HAD but a certain degree of coding might be needed

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Coding is fine. DYI a bit less, I'm more comfortable with software than hardware :)

Answer (score 7):

As you seem like a developer, a perfect fit for you would be any flavor of an Arduino. It is an easily programmable development controller with a massive backing of the maker community. This would allow you to take many inputs (skin sensors) and measure the voltage from 0-5v in 1024 steps, giving you 0.005v precision. This may not be precise enough, but a simple transistor can be used to amplify that signal (only a transistor and arduino is needed, no other circuitry unless you really want to go all out). Arduinos can be as small as your thumb or smaller and can even communicate over wifi using a shield. Cost is very cheap and the possibilities are endless. Because arduinos run simple code, you can set thresholds for flex strength, variables, and conditions that would not only allow you to click, but you can move your mouse precisely. This is much more powerful than the Makey Makey. You could probably get an official EEG, but that wouldn't give you the flexibility or functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks, isn't EEG for spotting electrical activity of the brain? or is it another acronym in the context of your answer?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt electroencephalograph. Usually used for measuring brain activity, yes, but can be used on any muscle because they work on electrical signals.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, in fact, one of the harder parts of working with an EEG is setting things up so the electrical signals from the facial muscles don't overwhelm the signals from the brain.

Comment: @Mark true I had quite some fun with neurosky... the emotiv headset seemed better from that standpoint.